# PayPal Express Checkout SOAP API: Refunds

Tags: c#, paypal

I use the PayPal Express Checkout SOAP service. For example here's a trimmed down version of the code to redirect the user to PayPal Sandbox when checking out:

```
var client = new PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient();

var credentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType() {
    Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType() { ... }
};

var paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType() {
    OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType() {
        Value = string.Format("{0:0.00}", 100m)
    }
};

var request = new SetExpressCheckoutReq() {
    SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType() {
        SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType() {
            PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType[] { paymentDetails },
            CancelURL = "http://www.mysite.com" + Url.Action("Cancelled", "PayPalCheckout"),
            ReturnURL = "http://www.mysite.com" + Url.Action("Index", "PayPalCheckout")
        },
        Version = "60.0"
    }
};

var response = client.SetExpressCheckout(ref credentials, request);

return Redirect(string.Format("{0}?cmd=_express-checkout&token={1}", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", response.Token));
```

I then handle the data when the user is returned to the ReturnUrl. This was taken from some code I found on another website.

I now need to add a refund facility to my site. I was wondering if anyone else has done this? I've tried searching online but can't seem to find anything that helps. I also tried doing it myself but the API isn't very intuitive.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would just need to be a RefundTransaction API call that you would need to execute.  Are you trying to have your return page issue a refund based on a condition, or are you trying to create a GUI type of interface to allow someone to issue a refund for a transaction?  Have you looked at the code samples for this within the [SDK's](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew) that PayPal offers?  You should be able to use this code.

Comment: Thanks the SOAP service I was using didn't have the RefundTransaction method. I downloaded the SDK and used that instead and all is fine.